# OpenCV: Extract the red light sources

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have an image in which there are a few red lights. I need to save the coordinates of its points in the array: [image]

And here's my code:

```
             red, green, blue = cv2.split(frame)
             rbin, thresholdImg = cv2.threshold(red, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)   

             new = np.argwhere(thresholdImg == 255)             #Get only RED pixels
             if len(new) != 0:                                  

                 xs = []
                 ys = []

                 n, m = new.shape
                 counter = 0
                 for (x,y) in new:  #Extract red pixels positions
                        xs = np.append(xs,y)
                        ys = np.append(ys,x)
```

Now in the arrays XS and YS I have the (x,y) coordinates of all "white" pixels respectively. I need to count the number of red lights and if they are 2, check whether the correct distance between them. So I tried to do it:

```
 if ((np.any(new[counter+1] - new[counter] >= minSeamLength)) and (np.any(new[counter+1] - new[counter] <= maxSeamLength))):
  ...
```

This way I tried to check if the size of the gap in the array fits me.
But this isn't working.

Any help?

Comment: Where exactly are the red lights? I see 3 red rings, are you talking about red pixels?

Comment: No. This picture is thresholded source Image so red color is white on it. I painted rings in the editor to select the 3 red light sources (in picture they are white areas)